# How to set java_home in ant build xml

Tags: java, ant

I need to run my project on java 1.4 and
pmd and findbugs on java 1.5
So, i need to set java_home in my build xml.

Thanks in advance,
-Sravan

Comment: you want to set it from ANT or for ant ?

Comment: Yes, i want to set it for ANT.
to build my src code on java 1.4  
and run pmd on java 1.5

Comment: which operating system ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a attribute called "jvm" for the java-task:

```
<java jvm="PATH_TO_YOUR_VM" fork="true"...>
...
</java>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are in Windows, you could create 2 batch files: one that sets JAVA_HOME to 1.3 followed by your call to ant, a second one that sets JAVA_HOME to 1.4 followed by your call to ant.
ex:

startAnt1.3.bat:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Java1.3\etc.
ant myTarget
```

startAnd1.4.bat:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Java1.4\etc.
ant myTarget
```